# Xcode13/ SwiftUI: Object detection app iOS

Tags: ios, coreml, resnet, vision, xcode13

I am building an object detection app using SwiftUI/Xcode and for image classification i used Resnet50. But there is an error. [init() is deprecated][1]. My code was

How to solve this issue. I am a beginner, please make it simple

//camera
let captureSession = AVCaptureSession()

```
    guard let captureDevice = AVCaptureDevice.default(for: .video) else { return }
    guard let input = try? AVCaptureDeviceInput(device: captureDevice) else { return }
    captureSession.addInput(input)
    
    captureSession.startRunning()
    
    let previewLayer = AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer(session: captureSession)
    view.layer.addSublayer(previewLayer)
    previewLayer.frame = view.frame
    
    
    // The camera is now created!
    
    view.addSubview(belowView)
    
    belowView.clipsToBounds = true
    belowView.layer.cornerRadius = 15.0
    belowView.layer.maskedCorners = [.layerMaxXMinYCorner, .layerMinXMinYCorner]
    
    
    let  dataOutput = AVCaptureVideoDataOutput()
    dataOutput.setSampleBufferDelegate(self, queue: DispatchQueue(label: "videoQueue"))
    captureSession.addOutput(dataOutput)
}
func captureOutput(_ output: AVCaptureOutput, didOutput sampleBuffer: CMSampleBuffer, from connection: AVCaptureConnection) {
    guard let pixelBuffer: CVPixelBuffer = CMSampleBufferGetImageBuffer(sampleBuffer) else { return }
```

***guard let model = try? VNCoreMLModel(for: model) else { return }*** (can't find model in scope)
let request = VNCoreMLRequest(model: model) { (finishedReq, err) in

```
        guard let results = finishedReq.results as? [VNClassificationObservation] else {return}
        guard let firstObservation = results.first else {return}
        
        let name: String = firstObservation.identifier
        let acc: Int = Int(firstObservation.confidence * 100)
        
        DispatchQueue.main.async {
            self.objectNameLabel.text = name
            self.accuracyLabel.text = "Accuracy: \(acc)%"
            
        }
    }
    
    try? VNImageRequestHandler(cvPixelBuffer: pixelBuffer, options: [:]).perform([request])
    
    
}
```

}

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need the configuration now to initialized it. Something like

```
static func createImageClassifier() -> VNCoreMLModel {
    // Use a default model configuration.
    let defaultConfig = MLModelConfiguration()

    // Create an instance of the image classifier's wrapper class.
    let imageClassifierWrapper = try? Resnet50(configuration: defaultConfig)

    guard let imageClassifier = imageClassifierWrapper else {
        fatalError("App failed to create an image classifier model instance.")
    }

    // Get the underlying model instance.
    let imageClassifierModel = imageClassifier.model

    // Create a Vision instance using the image classifier's model instance.
    guard let imageClassifierVisionModel = try? VNCoreMLModel(for: imageClassifierModel) else {
        fatalError("App failed to create a `VNCoreMLModel` instance.")
    }

    return imageClassifierVisionModel
}
```

Apple has really good sample code that gets you started.

https://developer.apple.com/documentation/vision/classifying_images_with_vision_and_core_ml

Comment: Thanks, it solved the problem. But I have got: can't find 'model' in scope. I have tried to clean it and deleting bridging headers but it does not work.                                                                 guard let model = try? VNCoreMLModel(for: model) else { return }

Comment: Hard to tell without more code. Note that the function that I posted is a static function so it can stay consistent. That could be an issue of not used correctly. Look at the sample code you will get a full setup.